# Comprendiendo la logica de line-height en css

Tags: css

comprendiendo la logica de line-height como funciona esta propiedad  de css

```
header .logo a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height: 100px; 

}

header .logo img {
    width:100px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Esto puede ayudar :) https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El line-height se usa para indicar el interlineado que permite controlar la altura ocupada por cada línea de texto. En tu caso estas diciendo que **header .logo a** tendra un interlineado de 100px y que la imagen se mostrará posicionado en base a ese interlineado, el efecto que veras es que si colocas un interlineado de mayor valor veras como baja el texto o la imagen y si colocas uno de menor valor subira, cuando digo que sube es como si le aplicases un margin-top con valores negativos, ese es el efecto que lograrias.

Si colocas un interlineado con el mismo valor a la altura, el efecto que veras es que tratará de centrarse con respecto a su contenedor, es decir si el line-height es igual al height

```css
#test1{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
}

#test2{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:100px;
  line-height:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">line-height 100px</div>
<div id="test2">line-height 10px</div>
```